# MVC in ASP 4.5, RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to set it up to automatically refresh the database. I have read other posts on here, and have tried the solutions, but I cannot get it to work. I am using ASP.NET Framework 4.5. I have only added 3 models and their controllers, but I cannot access them in the web browser. From what I've read it is because when I make any changes to the controllers the database isn't synching up with it properly. I have tried the Package Manager Console, using Enable-Migrations, and I have went in to Global.asax.cs, Application_Start(), and putting in:

```
Database.SetInitializer<This>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<This>());
```

My database and project is called This, as it is just a playaround demo for a project I have coming up. Under Data Connections, it lists my database as ThisContext (This), so I have also used/tried:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ThisContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ThisContext>());
```

Comment: So what is the specific problem you are having ? It is not recreating the db when model changes ? or your pages are not working ?

Comment: I get the following error (this is without the code I mentioned in Application_Start()) "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The model backing the 'ThisContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database " So I go in and try to add in    Database.SetInitializer<This>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<This>());, but I get red error line under the database I'm trying to reference, "This".

Answer (score 0):

To use automatic migration you have to fallow the next steps:

After each model change go to the Package Manager Console and add a new migration

```
add-migration MigrationName
```

In Configuration class set  AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

```
 public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ContextKey = "ReferresManager.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
    }
```

On Global.asax set

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
        migrator.Update();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

Comment: I get an error under DbMigrator, "The type or namespace name 'DbMigrator' could not be found."

Comment: you need using System.Data.Entity.Migration;